# Jenkins when with Build Trigger

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have a multibranch job in my jenkins, what I have a webhook setup from my github to my jenkins that send every pull request changes and issue comments.

What I'm trying to do is let github send the pull request changes for indexing purposes, but don't run the job, unless the developer add comment 'test' in the comment on the github pull request.

This is my `Jenkinsfile`,

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'mac' }
  stages {
    stage ('Check Build Cause') {
      steps {
        script {
           def cause = currentBuild.buildCauses.shortDescription
           echo "${cause}"
        }
      }
    }
    stage ('Test') {
      when {
        expression {
          currentBuild.buildCauses.shortDescription == "[GitHub pull request comment]"
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'bundle exec fastlane test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I want if the trigger isn't `GitHub pull request comment`, don't run anything. I've tried this but it doesn't work. I've tried print `currentBuild.buildCauses.shortDescription` variable and it prints `[GitHub pull request comment]`, but the job still won't run with my `when expression`

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to print buildCauses.shortDescription in your Test-Stage? Are you sure the description is equal to the string you compare? Your code looks fine imo.

Comment: I've tried printing it in my Test-Stage after deleting the when. It says exactly "[GitHub pull request comment]"

Comment: Maybe you have to take care of a second "? So something like "\"Github...\"" - just a guess from my side

Comment: no, it doesn't use the apostrophe, I've tried != and it doesn't skip the stage

Comment: Did you try to use ' instead of " for your comparison string? Source: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the problem is because `currentBuild.buildCauses.shortDescription` return ArrayList instead of plain String.

I didn't really think this was meant an array `[GitHub pull request comment]`, so I manage to fix the issue with just array index.

```
currentBuild.buildCauses.shortDescription[0]
```

This return the correct build trigger `GitHub pull request comment`. So for anyone who also stumbles to this issue, this is how I fixed it

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'mac' }
  stages {
    stage ('Test') {
      when {
        expression {
          currentBuild.buildCauses.shortDescription[0] == "GitHub pull request comment"
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'bundle exec fastlane test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```